# Migrate existing Mac installation to VirtualBox

Tags: mac, virtualbox, images, virtual-machine

Does anyone know how to make a .vdi .hdd .vmdk or .vhd image of my Mac? I need to make a perfect clone of my hard drive in one of these formats so I can clone my system in a VirtualBox VM (for development purposes).

Comment: What you are trying to do is not permitted by the OS X license agreement. You cannot run OS X on unsupported (read non-Apple) hardware, including in a virtual environment.

Comment: thank you for telling me what i already know. I would still like to know how to make the image.

Comment: @Randolph The legality and reach of licensing provisions differs from country to country. While mtmurdock is in the US, other users might legally be able to use this knowledge.

Answer (score 5):

It's completely legal if the host is also a Mac.

Use a disk cloning software (AFAIK CarbonCopyCloner/Superduper or anything else like that, not my area). It should be able to export to ISO. This command will apparently turn it into a virtualbox hard drive.

```
VBoxManage convertfromraw /path/to/output/disk-image.iso /path/to/output/disk-image.vdi
```

[Source](http://mortalpowers.com/news/convert-iso-file-to-virtualbox-hard-drive-vdi)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39159/is-it-possible-to-run-osx-in-a-virtual-machine) on StackOverflow.

It's only supported for OS X Server, and on an OS X host.

Comment: This isnt what i was asking. The thread you linked to is about created a new installation of OSX in a VM. I want to know how to make an image of my EXISTING system.

Comment: I'm failing to see the problem. Mac OS X supports restoring from a backup on Time Machine, right? And when you install Mac OS X, it asks you whether it's a clean install or a Time Machine restore. So, I figured you could put the two together and make a plan.